# JAVA REGEX:Make nested same values into single group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a Question in regex Expressions.

I want to make nested same values into a single group.

But,I was trying to using regular expression i won't work.

**Example String:**

```
<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
```

I want to get the three `<one></one>` tag as a single group.

How can I do this??

**My regex pattern is:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<one (.*?)>(.*?)</one>)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
```

**My result is:**

```
 group 1:<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
 group 1:<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
 group 1:<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
```

**I want:**

```
group 1:<one listtype="NumberList1">one</one><one listtype="NumberList1">one</one><one listtype="NumberList1">one</one>
```

I want to make this as a single group.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match three such `<one>` tags in succession, then just use an appropriate pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:<one (?:.*?)>(?:.*?)</one>\\s*){3})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Sorry, the regex I was using had a slight problem, it appears to be working now.

Comment: Thanks bro.But,just  in case it is more then 3 how can i capture bro.

Comment: Just change `{3}` to the number you want or use `*` for any number.

Comment: I'm trying this `((?:<one (?:.*?)>(?:.*?)</one>\\s*){*})` bro.But, It's given an Error like this `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 33
((?:<one (?:.*?)>(?:.*?)</one>\s*){*})`

Comment: I have answered your question.  Don't bro me if you don't know me.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.Did you try this `{*}'?

Comment: Just replace `{3}` with `*` if you want to match any number.

Comment: @MariSelvan I'm happpy to help you.  For next time, the clearer your question, the faster you will get help here.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice @Tim.I'll definitely follow your advice.Thank's again.